# network adapter will detect wifi but cannot connect to it lubuntu

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I have an very old laptop and I installed lubuntu on it.

I'm using Realtek wireless USB adaptor and it installs automatically, but even tho it detects the WiFi signal it won't connect to it.

What should I do in order to cause it connect to WIFI?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "Not connecting"?
There are several possible situations:

1. You are connected to Wifi but can't get IP Address
2. You can't connect to wifi network as authentication does not pass
3. You can't connect to Wifi at all as you can't find needed SSID (network name) at all.

Please provide following output:

> lsusb -v
>
> lshw -C network
>
> ifconfig
>
> iwlist WIFI_INTERFACE_NAME scan